# Is there an implementation of blocking queue which save the elements (and not the reference of the elements)?

Tags: java

I have a Consumer & Producer which use BlockingQueue (ArrayBlockingQueue) with ByeBuffer elements.

putting elements into the BlockingQueue - adds a reference to the BlockingQueue.
I need to use a blockingQueue which adds the element (not reference).
Is is possible to do so with java blockingQueue ?

Thanks

Comment: Java Always add reference to any collection.

Comment: Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value on the way objects are referenced in Java

Comment: No. There is no such thing as adding an *object* in java.The things that  that keep moving are references

Comment: Please write more about what you are trying to achieve or what problem you try to solve. We will get a better idea of the problem then. What you wrote so far seems to be an idea for a solution rather than the problem itself.

Comment: @TheLostMind At least, [not yet](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/169). But I suspect what OP could already do in this case is use immutable objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, thus ugly, for you to fill the queue with clones that you and not the collection will create.